Reduce the size of certain cells in table
In my table, some data appears on 2 lines because the content is probably too large.
I was thinking of reducing the size of the text in certain cells (cell {2}{2} to {5}{5}) but I'm not sure how I should specify this in my table preamble?
thanks

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]%
\begin{tblr}{
colspec = {lX[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]},
vline{2} = {1}{text=\clap{:}},
vline{3} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{+}}},
vline{4} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{->}}},
vline{5} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{+}}},
row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
colsep=2pt,
}
\toprule[blue]
équation                    & \ch{HA\aq{}}                                          & \ch{HO\mch{}\lqd{}}   & \ch{A\mch{}\aq{}}     & \ch{H2O\lqd{}} \\
\midrule[blue]
état initial                                        &  $n_a=C_a V_a$                                        &  $n_b=C_b V$              & $\approx 0$               & excès \\
état final $(V<V_{eq})$     &  $C_a V_a -C_b V=C_b (V_{eq}-V)$  &  $\approx 0$              &   $C_b V$                         & excès\\
état final $(V=V_{eq})$     &  $\approx 0$                                      & $\approx 0$               &   $C_b V_{eq}$                & excès\\
état final $(V>V_{eq})$     &  $\approx 0$                                      & $C_b V -C_a V_a=C_b(V-V{eq})$         &   $C_b V_{eq}$    & excès\\
\bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
\caption{Tableau d'avancement pour le dosage d'un acide faible par une base forte}
\label{tab:tableau_avancement_dosage_acide_faible_base_fort}
\end{table}



\end{document}


I think we need to know also your document "geometry".
I suggest something like this:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]%
\begin{tblr}{
colspec = {lX[2.7,c]X[2.8,c]X[c]X[c]},
columns={font=\small},
vline{2} = {1}{text=\clap{:}},
vline{3} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{+}}},
vline{4} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{->}}},
vline{5} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{+}}},
row{1}={font=\small\bfseries},
%colsep=2pt,
}
\toprule[blue]
équation                    & \ch{HA\aq{}}                                          & \ch{HO\mch{}\lqd{}}   & \ch{A\mch{}\aq{}}     & \ch{H2O\lqd{}} \\
\midrule[blue]
état initial                                        &  $n_a=C_a V_a$                                        &  $n_b=C_b V$              & $\approx 0$               & excès \\
état final $(V<V_{eq})$     &  $C_a V_a -C_b V=C_b (V_{eq}-V)$  &  $\approx 0$              &   $C_b V$                         & excès\\
état final $(V=V_{eq})$     &  $\approx 0$                                      & $\approx 0$               &   $C_b V_{eq}$                & excès\\
état final $(V>V_{eq})$     &  $\approx 0$                                      & $C_b V -C_a V_a=C_b(V-V{eq})$         &   $C_b V_{eq}$    & excès\\
\bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
\caption{Tableau d'avancement pour le dosage d'un acide faible par une base forte}
\label{tab:tableau_avancement_dosage_acide_faible_base_fort}
\end{table}



\end{document}


If you would like to change the font of a single cell, use cell{<row>}{<column>}={<options>}:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]%
\begin{tblr}{
colspec = {lX[2,c]X[2,c]X[c]X[c]},
columns={font=\footnotesize},
cell{3}{2}={font=\scriptsize},
cell{Z}{3}={font=\scriptsize},
vline{2} = {1}{text=\clap{:}},
vline{3} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{+}}},
vline{4} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{->}}},
vline{5} = {1}{text=\clap{\ch{+}}},
row{1}={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
colsep=2pt,
}
\toprule[blue]
équation                    & \ch{HA\aq{}}                                          & \ch{HO\mch{}\lqd{}}   & \ch{A\mch{}\aq{}}     & \ch{H2O\lqd{}} \\
\midrule[blue]
état initial                                        &  $n_a=C_a V_a$                                        &  $n_b=C_b V$              & $\approx 0$               & excès \\
état final $(V<V_{eq})$     &  $C_a V_a -C_b V=C_b (V_{eq}-V)$  &  $\approx 0$              &   $C_b V$                         & excès\\
état final $(V=V_{eq})$     &  $\approx 0$                                      & $\approx 0$               &   $C_b V_{eq}$                & excès\\
état final $(V>V_{eq})$     &  $\approx 0$                                      & $C_b V -C_a V_a=C_b(V-V{eq})$         &   $C_b V_{eq}$    & excès\\
\bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
\caption{Tableau d'avancement pour le dosage d'un acide faible par une base forte}
\label{tab:tableau_avancement_dosage_acide_faible_base_fort}
\end{table}
\end{document}



The option [!h] is bad.

@egreg Just copied from the OP.

@egreg My table comes from a more complete document and for reasons of consistency I want to freeze its location

@Nicolas You won’t. If a table can’t be placed, it will block all the others until the end of the chapter or article.
